# Session does not work with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, session

I have a directory that has files that are only used as modal.
These files are in PHP, in the following format: "modal.filename.php".
See the example:

"`modal.user.php`":

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 1;

echo '<pre>';

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

If I enter it directly, the result is:

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [test] => 1
)
```

If I call him by `AJAX` or `file_get_contents()`, the result is:

```
Array (
     [test] => 1
);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: file_get_contents() not get your sessions.

Comment: @Juninho Chr Show you ajax

Comment: @Nathan Srivi http://pastebin.com/3NMkjeLi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Ajax.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();    
    $_SESSION['test'] = 1;    

echo "<a onClick='sampelfun()' ><img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-akaW_RlCjTA/TjqNgp54JiI/AAAAAAAAB1o/8pZAz5XmGzA/s200/go%252520signlarge.gif'></a>";   

?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sampelfun()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "sample.php",
    success:function(html)
    {
    alert(html);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Sample.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['test'];

?>
```